# Clojure problem with my reduce method using sequence

Tags: clojure

I need to make solution for reduce method using only SEQUENCES and Recursion

My solution:

```
(defn my-reduce
  [f acc xs]
  (when (seq xs)
    (cons (f acc (first xs))
          (my-reduce f (f (first xs) acc) (next xs)))))

(my-reduce + 0 '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

It returns: `(1 3 6 10 15)`

How to edit my solution, to return only result of this sequence: `15`

Comment: Why are you `cons`tructing a sequence in the first place?

Comment: just for debug,

if i use `(my-reduce f (f (first xs) acc) (next xs))` it returns, nil :(

Comment: I've edited your code formatting on both the question and the answer. Feel free to change if you don't like it, but please some sort of code formatting conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

```
(defn my-reduce
  [f acc xs]
  (if (nil? xs) 
    acc
    (my-reduce f (f (first xs) acc) (next xs))))

(my-reduce + 0 '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Comment: `(= xs nil)` isn't idiomatic, prefer [`nil?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/nil_q)

Comment: maybe```(defn my-reduce
  ([f acc xs]
    (cond (nil? xs) acc
          :else (recur f (f acc (first xs)) (next xs))))
  ([f xs]
   (my-reduce f (first xs) (next xs))))```